Why the shape of array in Conv when fine-tuning MobileNetv2 doesn't match?
I'm trying to fine-tune a MobileNetv2 model from a checkpoint (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet, see "float_v2_1.4_224" under "Mobilenet V2 Imagenet Checkpoints") for the task of Image Segmentation with Deeplabv3. I've followed the approach described on the deeplab repo by replacing the pascal VOC dataset with my own, made up of images sized 224x224 (same size as the images used to train that checkpoint) and then used this script as reference for which flags to set for training mobilenetv2.(https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/local_test_mobilenetv2.sh)
This is the command I'm using:
 python deeplab/train.py
  --logtostderr 
  --train_split="train" 
  --model_variant="mobilenet_v2"
  --output_stride=16
  --train_crop_size="225,225" #images are 224x224, so it's set to this as per the tensorflow/research/deeplab FAQs
  --train_batch_size=4 
  --training_number_of_steps=100
  --fine_tune_batch_norm=true
  --dataset="custom" #defined properly as its own dataset
  --tf_initial_checkpoint="./deeplab/data_resized/initial_checkpoint/mobilenet_v2_1.4_224.ckpt"
  --train_logdir="./deeplab/data_resized/checkpoint"
  --dataset_dir="./deeplab/data_resized/ltfrecord"

But I keep on getting the following error:
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deeplab/train.py", line 464, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Luca\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\platform\app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.6\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.6\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "deeplab/train.py", line 444, in main
    ignore_missing_vars=True)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\Documents\marathon\facade_ml\training_gitclone\models-master\research\deeplab\utils\train_utils.py", line 221, in get_model_init_fn
    ignore_missing_vars=ignore_missing_vars)
  File "C:\Users\Luca\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\contrib\framework\python\ops\variables.py", line 690, in assign_from_checkpoint
    (ckpt_name, str(ckpt_value.shape), str(var.get_shape())))
ValueError: Total size of new array must be unchanged for MobilenetV2/Conv/weights lh_shape: [(3, 3, 3, 48)], rh_shape: [(3, 3, 3, 32)]

I've tried changing other configuration values such as "initialize_last_layer" to false and "last_layers_contain_logits_only" to false but this has not helped, and information on this issue seems non-existing both on Google and in GitHub. One user suggested changing the "depth_multiplier" flag to 0.5 and to 1.4 but it has not had any effect other than changing rh shape to [3,3,3,16] and [3,3,3,45]. I think dm=1.4 is the supposed value because it almost matches the shape closely, but there's some padding/lack of I can't understand.
Thank you for your help.

I looked into the MobileNetV2 architecture and the loaded weights from your link and there is at least a miss-match between for the first conv layer filters. It seems there exists "MobileNetV2 1.4" with 48 conv filters, where the normal MobileNetV2 has only 32 filters (I don't know if there are other differences, but this is enough to get the missmatch error you posted). TF uses the normal MobilNetV2, your weights come from the 1.4 version. Try to use the float_v2_1.0_224 weights.
